# Java classes with a collection of its own objects

Tags: java, object-oriented-analysis

I have fairly beginner to intermediate experience in object oriented programming.
In general, why or in what situations do we design a class that has a collection of its own objects as its member?
Is there a good example to understand this usage?

Comment: An example situation is designing a tree and its related classes. In that, a Node has a list of Nodes which might its Parent, Child, and Sibling Nodes.

Comment: Thanks,I have come across Trees like this where it might help in recursively solving problems. But I was looking for user defined classes where we want to be able to track objects belonging to a class in the program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such a Class/Type is called a Recursive Data Type or Recursive Data Structure. A tree structure for example consists of a bunch of node objects, each of it containing a list of child nodes.
See 
http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/198160-data-structures-recursion-stacks-and-trees/

A suiting software design pattern to model such a recursive structure in Java is called composite.
See https://dzone.com/articles/composite-design-pattern-java-0

Comment: The second link was what I was trying to understand! Not familiar with design patterns. Composite pattern is what this usage seems to be! Thanks!